# Difference between block and process statement in VHDL

Tags: vhdl

I recently ran into a question regarding VHDL block and process structures and didn't find any explanation in text books or internet forums.
Is there any difference between the block and the process statements in the codes bellow?

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;

entity example is
    port ( a, b, clock : in  std_logic;
           c           : out std_logic);
end entity;

architecture rtl of example is

begin
    test_block : block (clock'event and clock = '1')
    begin
        c <= guarded a and b;
    end block test;
end rtl;
```

and

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;

entity example is
    port ( a, b, clock : in  std_logic;
           c           : out std_logic);
end entity;

architecture rtl of example is

begin

    test_proc : process (clock)
    begin
        if (clock'event and clock = '1') then
            c <= a and b;
        end if;
    end process test_proc;

end rtl;
```

Comment: Nobody uses blocks. I wouldn't worry about it, if were you. (I teach VHDL and I don't know the answer.)

Comment: For the example you show there's probably no difference in function. However, there are much more possible constructs. The block statement is probably not supported in synthesis.

Comment: Block statements can be useful to group parts of your code which you do not want to split into multiple sub-modules. I actually use block statements sometimes and they can be synthesized with some (many?) restrictions. For example, ports on a block are not synthesizable AFAIK. (Well, it depends on your tool...)

Comment: Internal block statements are supported for synthesis, including guard expression. IEEE Std 1076.6-2004, withdrawn, 8.9.1, but not block headers - generic and port clauses, generic and port maps). An entity is an external block which is elaborated into an equivalent block statement (including header). Block statements represent design hierarchy and are concurrent statements. You're concurrent assignment statement in the block statement is elaborated into an equivalent sequential statement in a process statement. Your first example has an additional level of hierarchy.

Comment: An entity is a primary design unit, it is analyzed independently meaning it doesn't inherit visibility to declarations other than through the entity header (generic and port maps, through association) when instantiated as components. Your block statement requires c, a and b visibility from the outer declarative region. It also needs guarded assignment to produce a sequential element (flip flop) for c. (IEEE Std 1076.6-2004 6.1.3.6 Edge-sensitive storage using a guarded block).

Comment: I see no evidence in Xilinx XST/Vivado  for support of block statements. Quartus has historical support.

Comment: Thanks for the insights. I found out why the code I was examining uses this kind of structure: The developer actually implemented a "block like process" with "guarded" signals to use "when...else" structures inside, since a usual "process" wouldn't allow it.

Answer (score 0):

The main difference is in the keyword `guarded`. If you write your code without it, whole logic would be regular **combinational**. So, I guess, if you want to write mostly concurrent code with some **sequential** logic, you can carefuly use `block` statement and when sequential needed use `guarded`. I've asked my colleagues who have huge background in FPGA design and they told that `block` is kinda anachronism, almost nobody use it, but it still in standard to give some choice for designers.